# Docker : How to export/save classifying results outside a Docker (tensorflow) box?

Tags: python, csv, docker, tensorflow

I just followed this tutorial to easily train an image classifier with tensorflow :

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/

I now have a Docker box on my Ubuntu laptop, I managed to train the image classifier, and IT WORKS. Now I want to classify a batch of new images and **store results (i.e. probabilities) on my laptop**.

My objective is to save on my laptop the following results in an "output.csv" file like this:

```
pic1    0.95   0.05
pic2    0.94   0.06
pic3    0.97   0.03
pic4    0.09   0.91
```

I put new images in a "tested" folder and I run the following python code, trying to write in an output file.

Inside Docker terminal I run:

```
python /tf_files/label_batch_images.py /tf_files/tested
```

where label_batch_images.py code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf, sys
import glob

folder_path = sys.argv[1]

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    out = open('output.csv', 'a')

    for image_path in glob.glob(folder_path+'/*'):

        # Read in the image_data
        image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

        # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                 {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

        print("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (image_path,predictions[0][1],predictions[0][0]))
        #THIS ACTUALLY WORKS, I see in my terminal "/tf_files/tested/pic1.jpg   0.00442768  0.995572"
        out.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (image_path,predictions[0][1],predictions[0][0]))
        #This does not work, because output.csv is not modified

    out.close()
```

While it works - I see the expected results for each image in my Docker terminal - how to save it on a file on my laptop ?

Comment: It helps to read the docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### use volumes

Share a so called host volume with your host, laptop, to write down the results directly on the host. e.g when starting your image

`docker run -v /home/me/docker/results:/data/results <image>`

In your container, when you write on /data/results, all files will be synced back / placed on the host under /home/me/docker/results

You can of course adjust both, the host or the container path

### user docker cp

You can easily copy file from a docker container ( or to a docker container ) user `docker cp`

so

```
docker cp <yourimageid>:/path/to/the/file/on/the/container /home/me/docker/results
```

Do this, before you shutdown the container

Comment: To expand on this, the particular example uses the first method to map /tf_files/ on the Docker image to tf_files in your user folder on OS X, so any files you save there should already be shareable across both operating systems.